# Why has my Google Maps API key become invalid?

Tags: api, google-maps, key

It's my first question here and I didn't found an answer in my research.

I've got a probleme with my google map API key, on a old site (not mine). tao-yin.com ( French associations of Qiqong). There's 2 months, i did a map for this website (in 2 places).

Here : http://www.tao-yin.com/arts_classiques_tao/liste_associations.html

and here : http://www.tao-yin.com/pratique-qi-gong/Cours_stages.htm

Everything was ok, for a while. It's a map with Accessing Arguments in UI Events.
Now, I learned that, (as you can see it) the 2 map are out because the key is invalid.
The English error message:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The
>   provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized
>   for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the
>   owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key
>   here:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Obtaining_Key

I'm suprised. Why is the key no longer valid but was ok before ?
I read that the v2 is not more valid since the 19 may, but it's a v3key (activatedd). And for the code (i'm not an expert) I took an exemple for v3 on the internet.

1. I tried to change the key and erase the old : same problem
2. I tried 2 key ( one for map) : same problem
3. I tried to change the code javascript with a another one ( a google example) : same problem
4. I tried to make a better html code : same probleme

I don't know what happened. I think i break a rule , but wich one ? It's for a friend, for an association. It's for free.

Somebody have an idea ?

I don't not what to do: how can i put a googlemap on this website ? I read that it's possible directly with googlemap and an iframe, but i need specific event. Not just an address.

Comment: Bienvenue à Stackoverflow. I tided up your question a bit.

Comment: I have the same problem, code was ok and working and suddenly i'm unable to get it working with my key...

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution, it's very simple:

the problem was in the declaration of the website in the API key.

In the windows of declaration we have this exemple to followon the bottom.

> Example: *.example.com/*.

But, here :  https://developers.google.com/console/help/?hl=fr#restrictingusage
URL Pattern : the good choice.
It's logic.

Before i had : ".tao-yin.com/" 
and it was working (so i don't ask more) but it's not logic because its not on a subdomains.

Now everything is ok with : "www.tao-yin.com"

So : don't follow the example of Google ;-) juste follow the instruction.
Thank's to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps keys are tied to the referring URL hostname.  You may wish to get yourself a key for development; they are free.

It's possible, but unlikely, that they have killed your friend's key because his site was very busy and was generating more than the allowable map requests.  I don't think they kill the keys in this case, but rather just refuse the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
In fact, i generate the old key very simply with my google account whitout probleme. And it had worked fine. And the site is not a popular one. Even more map's page. I try an other solution like take the code of an exemple of google himself, on a new free htm : Same conlusion. Indeed the map appear and disapear subitly with the error message of the api key. I'm thinking that the web site is blacklisted or there is a probleme with the hosting service. I'm wondering if it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

This link also helps.  It shows a table of which google mapping products/APIs and the associated keys needed to use them:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem